# In the Discussions tag filter, trying to correct a minor typo clears the inputted text

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, discussions-space

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the [discussions overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions)
2. Open the tag filter
3. Type in some text. For example "javascrio"*
4. Attempt to fix this by pressing Backspace

Expected: The input now says "javascri" and the "o" is removed. 
Actual: All the text so far is removed. Any tags already added do stay but you have to start typing the tag name from zero.

Additional information: same behaviour when using the Delete button.

[image: The tag filter on the main discussions page with text filled in.]

---

* If you are <s>amazing</s> like me, then you just try to type in "javascript" normally but fat fingers can naturally produce a similar typo.

Comment: Interesting, I get the same behavior, when I try.

Comment: Maybe it is in VIM mode .... Not sure how you exit that ...